# Django: Elastic Beanstalk - cannot create new RDS database. [DBSubnets: Invalid option value]

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I used `eb-create` in the EB CLI to spin up a new application environment. However, when I tried to create a new database, it required me to select at least at least two availability zones from a list of four.

No matter which two I selected it would stop me with an error using the following language:

```
DBSubnets: Invalid option value [...] Specify the VPC ID and make sure all subnets exist.
```

I tried enabling the same options in the VPC configuration, but I was told this couldn't be done on an existing environment. It took me a while to find the answer, so I am posting it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following EB CLI command properly initiated my environment and resulted in successful deployment of my application:

```
eb create --database.engine postgres
```

There are a few other settings you can provide from here as well. Please [refer to the docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html) for additional assistance.