# eb create from rds snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, rds

there is any way to use eb create command to create an evironment with RDS from an existing snapshot? (or something similar).

I use a cfg.yml file as a template for building my environment in case I need to rebuild it from scratch. I know that I could create a standalone RDS instance and connect it to my environment, but as I understand, I need to configure security groups to let my environment see the RDS db. Due I don't want to fall in missconfigurations (I'm not very into networking configuration and I'm looking for a quick solution) I would use an "automatic process". Previosly I would have used the eb console (not an automatic process but something in between), but as [you may know](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32670749/django-elastic-beanstalk-cannot-create-new-rds-database-dbsubnets-invalid) it isn't working now. I have looked on [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-create.html) but it seems to don't have any option for this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the `DBSnapshotIdentifier` setting in your config file to specify an RDS snapshot. It doesn't look like you can specify a snapshot directly via the `eb create` command.